# Deleting a folder in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, directory

I created a folder in a TFS Project under workspace "CPortalWS".  I deleted the workspace, but now I would like to delete the folder in the project and the delete option is not available.

I've tried to create a new workspace mapped to the project but I still don't get the option to delete.

Is this a bug in TFS?  How can I delete the folder?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Deleting a folder in TFS is a little strange.

You have to:

- Create a Workspace
- Get the latest source for the folder (to your local machine)
- Inside Source Explorer, delete the folder
- Check in your changes (this is the step that deletes the folder in Source Control)

Comment: Awesome Justin, I was missing the "Get Latest" part, I just assumed the assigning of the workspace would bind it - my bad.

Thanks!

Comment: only note that delete is not an actual delete. the folders/files are still there and kept in Version Control, for example for Undelete scenarios. you can see them and avail the undelete function if you go to "Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" and check "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer"

Comment: That's insane. I never want to see TFS again.

Comment: You did well, Justin.  I like TFS, but I agree that it should be easier to delete a folder.  Perhaps they intentionally make it difficult as deleting something can potentially be disastrous!

Comment: Boggles the mind why this was necessary to delete an _empty_ folder... >.<

Comment: Because Source Control is meant to be a permanent record. Having the ability to destroy, while perhaps necessary in very specific circumstances (though I do not believe it EVER is), it is generally creating a fraudulent record of what has happened.

Answer (score 24):

only note that delete is not an actual delete.
the folders/files are still there and kept in Version Control, for example for Undelete scenarios. 
You can see them and avail the undelete function if you go to "Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" and check "Show deleted items in the Source Control Explorer" and then right-click on one of the deleted folders.

so, if you want real delete, where the folder/files actually go away you need to use the Destroy Command which is only available from the command line, see link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx

Answer (score 14):

When you delete in TFS, it does not remove it from TFS. It maintains a copy of the deleted files, even when you check in the deletion. This can cause some issues. 
To permanently delete from TFS, you need to issue a `tfs destroy` command.

To do this:

1. Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt.
2. Issue the following command: `tf destroy $/SourceLocation/Folder`. Where $/SourceLocation/Folder is the Source location of the deleted folder in TFS.

Please note: This command will also delete the file(s) from disk.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, where I had 1 folder which despite being deleted from Hard drive, was still showing as in Source Control (with a green + by the folder). It also showed me the content but if I tried to open any, an error message informed me the file wasn't there.

Clicking on any folder didn't show the delete button. I then realised that selecting a file did! If you don't have a file, create a text file and add it to the folder you want to delete (via Source Control). Click this file, note the delete shows. Select a folder and note that the delete disappears but only after half a second. This small delay is actually usable.

I clicked the file, so the delete button is enabled and hovered the mouse above the delete button. Using the keyboard, I did a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and as soon as all files and folders were selected I clicked left mouse button. And it worked! Everything was removed, including (and this is the odd thing) the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Workspace; and get latest on the base folder; Dont forget to cloak the relevant folders. If you are going to delete the subfolders then cloak all and get latest on the base folder. So you save a lot of time in pulling files.